# What does 'Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t'' mean in Objective C and how do I fix it?

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing an exercise from a textbook and the book is outdated, so I'm sort of figuring out how it fits into the new system as I go along. I've got the exact text, and it's returning

> 'Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int''.

The book is "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X" by Aaron Hillegass, third edition and the code is:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

-(IBAction)generate:(id)sender
{
    // Generate a number between 1 and 100 inclusive
    int generated;
    generated = (random() % 100) + 1;

    NSLog(@"generated = %d", generated);

    // Ask the text field to change what it is displaying
    [textField setIntValue:generated];
}

- (IBAction)seed:(id)sender
{
    // Seed the randm number generator with time
    srandom(time(NULL));
    [textField setStringValue:@"Generator Seeded"];
}

@end
```

It's on the `srandom(time(NULL));` line.

If I replace `time` with `time_t`, it comes up with another error message:

> Unexpected type name 'time_t': unexpected expression.

I don't have a clue what either of them mean. A question I read with the same error was apparently something to do with 64- and 32- bit integers but, heh, I don't know what that means either. Or how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't have a clue what either of them mean. A question I read with the same error was apparently something to do with 64- and 32- bit integers but, heh, I don't know what that means either. Or how to fix it.

Well you really need to do some more reading so you understand what these things mean, but here are a few pointers.

When you (as in a human) count you normally use decimal numbers. In decimal you have 10 digits, 0 through 9. If you think of a counter, like on an electric meter or a car odometer, it has a fixed number of digits. So you might have a counter which can read from 000000 to 999999, this is a six-digit counter.

A computer represents numbers in binary, which has two digits 0 and 1. A Binary digIT is called a BIT. So thinking about the counter example above, a 32-bit number has 32 binary digits, a 64-bit one 64 binary digits.

Now if you have a 64-bit number and chop off the top 32-bits you *may* change its value - if the value was just 1 then it will still be 1, but if it takes more than 32 bits then the result will be a different number - just as truncating the decimal 9001 to 01 changes the value.

Your error:

> Implicit conversion looses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'

Is saying you are doing just this, truncating a large number - `long` is a 64-bit signed integer type on your computer (not on every computer) - to a smaller one - `unsigned int` is a 32-bit unsigned (no negative values) integer type on your computer.

In your case the loss of precision doesn't really matter as you are using the number in the statement:

> srandom(time(NULL));

This line is setting the "seed" - a random number used to make sure each run of your program gets different random numbers. It is using the time as the seed, truncating it won't make any difference - it will still be a random value. You can silence the warning by making the conversion explicit with a *cast*:

```
srandom((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

But remember, if the *value* of an expression is important such casts can produce mathematically incorrect results unless the value is known to be in range of the target type.

Now go read some more!

HTH

Comment: This long explanation covers the error but doesn't show any solution of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a notification. You are assigning `'long' to 'unsigned int'`

Solution is simple. Just click the yellow notification icon on left ribbon of that particular line where you are assigning that value. it will show a solution. Double click on solution and it will do everything automatically.

It will typecast to match the equation. But try next time to keep in mind the types you are assigning are same.. hope this helps..